# How to achieve jQuery fade in and fade out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery fade in and fade out, I want my current page to fade out when a link on the navigation bar is selected and then I want the new page to fade in. I am unable to get the anticipated effect.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('display', 'none');
  $('body').fadeIn(2000);

  $('a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = this.href;
    $('body').fadeOut(2000, newpage);
  });

  function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
  }
});
```

Comment: the `fadeOut` happens of the first page? the `fadeIn` should be in the target/next page's code  right?

Comment: Instead of using window.location take a look into using Ajax to load the new page and insert it into the DOM without a full page refresh. Nice and slick :D Here is a good example: http://pjax.heroku.com/

Comment: So what's happening instead of the desired effect? Your page isn't fading out? The new page isn't fading in? The page isn't navigating to the new location?

Comment: The fadeOut should happen of the first page and the fadeIn should be in the target/next page's code . The fade in is working fine but the fade out is NOT WORKING. Thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Let's your navigation link is:

```
<a href="nextPage.html" class="switch">My LINK</a>
```

Then your jquery code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').css('display', 'none');

    $('body').fadeIn(2000);

    $('a.switch').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        newLocation = this.href;

        $('body').fadeOut(2000, newpage);

    });

    function newpage() {

        window.location = newLocation;

    }

});
```

Don't forget to put the event as an argument to the function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks, but still with this, I am not getting the fade out effect on the current page, when I go the new page from he current page, using the link on the navigation bar. Fade in effect is working perfect. Please help .Thank you.

Comment: Yes the fadeOut should happen of the first page and the fadeIn should be in the target/next page's code .

Comment: So probably your current page either doesn't have a `<body>` tags and if they have then it doesn't cover the entire page at all. Try to wrap the content of the current page with the `<body>` tag to get effect. you may still give the class name to body tag like `<body class= "current_page"> My content</body>` and then use: `$('body.current_page').fadeOut(2000, newpage);`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, now my FADE IN AND FADE OUT IS WORKING FINE .Ved Prakash your code is perfect. Thank you so much. Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: Well now the problem is that the time between the transition of 2 pages is about 3 to 4 seconds which is quite long. I want to keep it minimal. Please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to will's suggestion. The best way to achieve this is to prevent a whole reload of your page. Use Ajax or `.load()` function ! "Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element." Once the content is loaded, fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<body style="display:none;">
content
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function redirectPage() {
  window.location = linkLocation;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").fadeIn(600);

$('a').click(function(event) {
    if (this.href == "" || this.href == null) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    if ((this.href.indexOf("#") == -1) && (this.href.indexOf("mailto:") == -1) && (this.href.indexOf("javascript:") == -1) && (this.target != "_blank")) {
      event.preventDefault();
      linkLocation = this.href;
      $("body").fadeOut(600, redirectPage);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but there is still a 4 second lag between the transition of pages. Please help. I heard that AJAX can solve the issue but I have never implemented it so I dont know. Please guide me.